# Copy filenames from one folder to another

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have 2 folders with a lot of files.

First folder has image files with filenames:

```
0_01_23_982__0_01_26_692.jpeg 
0_01_26_985__0_01_29_987.jpeg
0_02_15_992__0_02_19_995.jpeg
 etc.
```

Second folder has text files with filenames:

```
Untitled.FR12 - 0001.txt
Untitled.FR12 - 0002.txt
Untitled.FR12 - 0003.txt
 etc.
```

Could anyone tell me, please, how can I copy filenames from first folder and rename files in second folder with them:

```
0_01_23_982__0_01_26_692.txt
0_01_26_985__0_01_29_987.txt
0_02_15_992__0_02_19_995.txt
 etc.
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33066072/7552

Comment: @glennjackman, I think it fits here better than there.

Comment: Yes, it's duplicate, because I want to find solution faster. And on each site are different professionals.

Comment: Guys, we can't close a question as a duplicate of one on another site, and it's on-topic here so we can't migrate it to SO for closure there as a dupe.  @WalterStolz: You've posted an answer.  In another day you will be able to accept it.  No need for anybody to do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
Here is the solution:

1) Create list with filenames from first folder (run in command window):

```
dir /b > output.txt
```

2) Open Rename Master program and switch to **Textfile** tab.
3) Press **Run Text file Wizard**.
4) Press button **Next**.
5) On Step 1 select output.txt file and press **Next** button.
6) On Step 2 press **Next** button.
7) On Step 3 press **Next** button.
8) On Step 4 select **Replace entire filename** option and press **Next** button.
9) On Final Step 4 press **Finish** button.
10) Press **+** icon and select **Remove Beginning/Ending**.
11) Set number of your old extention characters (5 for .jpeg)
12) In first drop-down list select **Name's**.
13) In second drop-down list select **Ending**.
14) Press button **Rename**.

That's All!