# Copy folder filenames ONLY to duplicate image folder

Tags: filenames

I have 400 Raw images edited and saved as Jpeg.  I have individually re-named each Jpeg. (none sequential numbering-though the structure of the folder is identical to the original RAW files)

I want to copy the jpeg filenames to the RAW image folder, over-writing the generic RAW filenames.

Comment: Do the old and new names have any common elements? Can you [edit] the question and give some examples? It's hard to understand what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Hi David.  No common elements at all.

Original RAW folder for instance is IMG-001

Saved as, for instance; Polo 53-17 C2.jpg

However each saved file has a completely different name.

Comment: Then it doesn't sound possible. Unless there is metadata tying the .jpg to the .raw. Then something might be done using PowerShell

Comment: In case this is still not clear.

I have 2 identical folders containing 10 files in each.  However, folder A is RAW files with generic IMG-001, IMG-002-IMG-010.  Folder B has the same 10 files inthe same sequence but saved with individual filenames as jpegs.

I want to copy the jpeg filenames to the RAW folder.

I'm struggling to see how there is not a simple answer to this.

Comment: Could you use a common language? What does "copy jpeg filenames" mean? What is "Copy folder filenames ONLY to duplicate image folder" supposed to mean?

Comment: The question is how to know which jpg goes with with raw so you can overwrite the correct file? Or you don't care about that?

Comment: I'm not a programmer.  I've no Idea what a 'common language is, sorry.

I have opened a RAW image, edited the file and saved it as a jpeg but with it's individual title relating to that image.  I the RAW file (IMG-001) was an image of the colour Orange, I would save the jpeg as Orange. 

I want to copy the saved jpeg filename OVER the RAW filename.  Therefore RAW 'IMG-001' would become 'Orange', but still remain a RAW file.

Comment: David I do care.

Both folders are identical in structure.  I simply want to copy new filenames to overwrite RAW filenames

Comment: I have found this which maybe a similar issue, but I don't understand the Answer. 
http://superuser.com/questions/985129/copy-filenames-from-one-folder-to-another

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you did:

1. Open RAW file (not in any specific order).
2. Save as JPEG.
3. Change name of JPEG.

Now you want to change RAW filename to be the same as a corresponding JPEG filename (renamed output of that RAW file)?

You can't do that, because there is nothing that would connect these two files. There will be a solution, if you find any connection between them.

Comment: They are edited in sequence hagier.  the saved folder is in the same sequence as the RAW folder.

imagine they are 2 folders side by side.  they are identical apart ffrom the file Type.  In this case, RAW and Jpeg.

as is stated in this link, but I do not understand the answer.  
http://superuser.com/questions/985129/copy-filenames-from-one-folder-to-another

Comment: They propably mean [this software](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/) in the answer.  Rest are just steps to do. If you have problem with step 1, you need to righ click in a folder, when holding shift, and click "Open command window here".

Comment: ah, i see.

I have managed to use the Cmd Prompt to copy the content filenames to Notepad.

Now I need to know how to apply that list to my RAW folder.

To re-iterate, the RAW folder is in the same sequence as the Jpeg folder.  This is the only commonality, other than the date they were created maybe

Comment: OK hagier, so I have managed to copy the filenames in to notepad, but they have lost the order they are in.  they have deferred to an alph/numeric order and not the order of the folder structure.  Any ideas on this?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand "order of the folder structure". You can order files in folder by name, time, etc. If you need to achieve same order, you can use `/O` (letter 'o') switch for `dir` command. Just type `dir /?` for more explanation.

Comment: OK, I give up.  I'm not going to get very far If I can't even put my question down right.

The file sequencing is identical in each folder.  RAW Files are the same as the Edited jpegs. in sequence.  So in folder RAW I have images 1-10 in sequence as they were shot..  In jpeg folder I have images 1-10 also in sequence they were shot..  But i have changed the name of the jpegs images.  The names are not sequential in numbers or letters, but they are still in the same order as the RAW files.

therefore I just want to copy the entire jpeg filename and paste it over the RAW filenames.

Comment: So you mean that in folder you see them in some order. If I understand correctly they are in order of being modified. Then you have to use command `dir /O:D /B > output.txt`. This is because **command needs to 'know'** how you want them ordered (it doesn't know how you see them - this is not how computer works). :)

Comment: No, both folders are in order of them being 'created' not modified.  So even though they have been edited and saved as jpeg and renamed, they are in identical order.

I'm currently looking at the software in the link above.  there is a 'Swap Filename' option but little instruction that I can understand to implement it.

Thank you for your patience. :D

Comment: Sadly, I can only help you with command line: `dir /T:C /O:D > output.txt`. I have never used this software before. :(

Comment: hagier, if you have a simpler way than the software I'd love to hear it.  I'm currently copying each and every filename one at a time and pasting/renaming my RAW files individually.  It's not ideal.

I've no Idea what to do comman line wise, especially what to do afterward.

if you understand my issue and can give me a line by line instruction, that would be amazing of you. :D

Comment: I could try to provide you some PowerShell script that might work but will you be able to use it? :) If it will take very much time to explain it, I'm sure it will be easier to do it manually.

Comment: ah probably not hagier.  I would like to know the answer as I think this would be a great tool to have, but I suppose i better just get on with it the long way round.  That is, copying pasting each filename.  :(

Thanks for everything so far.  Much appreciated.